# Web service needs to return an array but instead returns nothing

Tags: c#, arrays, web-services, class

I am writing my first web service and seem to be having some issues. I am having no problem at all returning a single result but when I attempt to return an array of custom class objects I just get nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Web Service

```
public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    private string strCrossoverConnection = "Connection String";

    [WebMethod]
    public CompetitorMatch[] GetCloseCompetitorMatches(string partNumber, string member)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCrossoverConnection))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[SelectClosestMatch]", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 6000;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SimplePart", partNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CurrentMember", member);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isClosestMatch", 1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isQuickSearch", 0);
            CompetitorMatch[] competitorPartMatches = null; 
            con.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);

                int resultCount = dt.Rows.Count;
                if (resultCount  > 0)
                {
                    competitorPartMatches = new CompetitorMatch[resultCount ];
                    for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
                    {
                        competitorPartMatches[i].PartNumber = dt.Rows[i]["Part Number"].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return competitorPartMatches;
        }
    }

    public class CompetitorMatch
    {
        private string m_partNumber;
        public CompetitorMatch() { }
        public CompetitorMatch(string partNumber){
            partNumber = PartNumber;
        }

        public string PartNumber { get { return m_partNumber; } set { m_partNumber = value; } }
    }
}
```

Return:

```
<CompetitorMatch xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://codeproject.com/webservices/"/>
```

Comment: put your return below for loop, the part where you wrote return; change it to return null

Comment: well, this may be doinng the same thing too, maybe sql gets nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are getting results from the database, you forget to create new instances for inside the array:

```
...
competitorPartMatches = new CompetitorMatch[resultCount];
for (int i = 0; i < resultCount; i++)
{
    competitorPartMatches[i] = new CompetitorMatch(); // <-- CREATE NEW INSTANCE!
    competitorPartMatches[i].PartNumber = dt.Rows[i]["Part Number"].ToString();
}
...
```